# django migrate error : 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'last_login', table

Tags: python, django, django-mssql

I have installed below versions

**Django==1.8**

**django-mssql==1.8**

**pypiwin32==220**

**pytz==2017.3**

and my **setting.py** file is as below.

----------------Start of setting.py------------------

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

"""DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'shetdb',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'ppp@123',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
            'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True',
            'use_mars': True
        }
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

-------------------End of setting.py file----------------------------

with these settings , I am not able to create super user/admin for sample application. 
When i try to createsuperuser using command
**>python manage,py createsuperuser**
it asks for username/email and password (2 times) after entering and hitting enter, I am getting below error in console.

---------------------------start-----------------------------------------------

```
Email address: p@123
Error: Enter a valid email address.
Email address: p@123.com
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 547, in _execute_command
    recordset = self.cmd.Execute()
  File "<COMObject ADODB.Command>", line 3, in Execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'last_login', table 'shetdb.dbo.auth_user'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.", None, 0, -2147217873), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 647, in execute
    self._execute_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 558, in _execute_command
    self._raiseCursorError(klass, _message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 488, in _raiseCursorError
    eh(self.connection, self, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 103, in standardErrorHandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
sqlserver_ado.dbapi.IntegrityError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'last_login', table 'shetdb.dbo.auth_user'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.", None, 0, -2147217873), None)
Command:
SET NOCOUNT ON;DECLARE @sqlserver_ado_return_id table ([id] int);INSERT INTO [auth_user] ([password], [last_login], [is_superuser], [username], [first_name], [last_name], [email], [is_staff], [is_active], [date_joined]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] INTO @sqlserver_ado_return_id VALUES (?, NULL, ?, ?, '', '', ?, ?, ?, ?);SELECT * FROM @sqlserver_ado_return_id
Parameters:
['Name: p0, Dir.: Input, Type: adVarWChar, Size: 77, Value: '
 '"pbkdf2_sha256$20000$GlZS9GZjXEMH$A33R/aR6QaF4Gy9x92K6aYJNluWf/+T+GdoAwE91vJY=", '
 'Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p2, Dir.: Input, Type: adBoolean, Size: -1, Value: "True", Precision: '
 '0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p3, Dir.: Input, Type: adVarWChar, Size: 12, Value: "praveenshetg", '
 'Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p6, Dir.: Input, Type: adVarWChar, Size: 9, Value: "p@123.com", '
 'Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p7, Dir.: Input, Type: adBoolean, Size: -1, Value: "True", Precision: '
 '0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p8, Dir.: Input, Type: adBoolean, Size: -1, Value: "True", Precision: '
 '0, NumericScale: 0',
 'Name: p9, Dir.: Input, Type: adVarWChar, Size: 26, Value: '
 '"2017-11-07T10:58:39.397247", Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0']

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
```

-------------------------------end------------------------------
I tried removing admin and auth from installedapps settings
it works fine but admin page is not accessible.

```
enter code here
```

Please suggest way to fix this to create super user and access admin page.

Comment: Did you apply all migrations before creating a super user?`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes @Trilliput, with the mentioned version it was not working. I changed the version of django-mssql==1.8 to 1.6 after that it worked  :)